# How to browse subdirectories at ftp server

Tags: java, swing, ftp, jtable, jprogressbar

I am building a swing FTP client.
Here is my code for jframe :-

```
package jframe;
import jframe.swing.download.*;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import test.FtpClient;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class UndecoratedFrameDemo {
private static Point point = new Point();
ArrayList arrayList;
static String server = "";
static int port = 21;
static String user = "";
static String pass = "";
JPopupMenu popup;
    public UndecoratedFrameDemo()
    {
        final Ftp_by_apache ftpByApache=new Ftp_by_apache(server,user,pass);
 arrayList=ftpByApache.getAllFile("/");
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("FTP Client By MPST");
    frame.setUndecorated(false);
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            point.x = e.getX();
            point.y = e.getY();
        }
    });
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = frame.getLocation();
            frame.setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - point.x,
                    p.y + e.getY() - point.y);
        }
    });

    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setLocation(300, 150);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Image icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("ftp-big-icon.jpg").getImage();
    frame.setIconImage(icon);
    Container pane=frame.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
       menuBar.add(file);

    JMenuItem New = new JMenuItem("New Server");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*code for new ftp server*/
        }
    });
    file.add(New);

    JMenuItem rename = new JMenuItem("Rename");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*code for rename*/
        }
    });
    file.add(rename);

    JMenuItem delete = new JMenuItem("Delete");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*code for delete*/
        }
    });
    file.add(delete);

    JMenuItem connect = new JMenuItem("Connect");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*code for connect to differnt ftp*/
        }
    });
    file.add(connect);

    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    file.add(item);


    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(edit);

    JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /* code for copy*/
        }
    });
    edit.add(copy);

    JMenuItem paste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /* code for Paste*/
        }
    });
    edit.add(paste);
    JMenuItem mkdir = new JMenuItem("New Directory");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    file.add(mkdir);

        popup = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem popupcopy= new JMenuItem("Copy");
        popup.add(popupcopy );
        JMenuItem popuprename= new JMenuItem("Rename");
        popup.add( popuprename );
        JMenuItem popupdelete= new JMenuItem("Delete");
        popup.add( popupdelete );
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                Component c = (Component)event.getSource();
                JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)c.getParent();
                JTable table = (JTable)popup.getInvoker();

                System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + " : " + table.getSelectedColumn());
                if(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn()+1).equals("File Folder"))
                {

                    System.out.println("File Folder Clicked");
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);

                }
                else
                {
                    try {


                 ftpByApache.download(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn()).toString(),"X:/");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        popup.add(menuItem);

    FileTableModel fileTableModel =new FileTableModel(arrayList) ;
    JTable table = new JTable(fileTableModel)
    {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int column)
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("pressed");
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    JTable source = (JTable) e.getSource();
                    int row = source.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                    int column = source.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

                    if (!source.isRowSelected(row))
                        source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);

                    popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
new UndecoratedFrameDemo();
}

public String[] getDir(String dir){ //Gets all of the directories from a given directory and returns them as a String Array
    String[] directories;
    try{


        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        FTPFile[] objects = ftpClient.listDirectories(dir);
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        directories = new String[objects.length];
        for(int i=0; i<objects.length; i++){
            directories[i]=objects[i].getName();
        }
        return directories;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        String[] dir1={};
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        return dir1;

    }
}

}
```

And here is my ftp class code

```
package jframe;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageInputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.*;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;


public class Ftp_by_apache {


FTPClient f = null;

//
public Ftp_by_apache(String url, String username, String password) {
    f = new FTPClient();
    //
    f.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    this.get_connection(url, username, password);

}

public String printTime(String time) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
    try {
        String timePart = time.split(" ")[1];
        Date modificationTime = dateFormat.parse(timePart);
        System.out.println("File modification time: " + modificationTime);
        return modificationTime.toString();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "undefined";
    }
}

//
public void get_connection(String url, String username, String password) {


    try {

        f.connect(url);
        System.out.println("connect success!");


        f.setControlEncoding("GBK");


        boolean login = f.login(username, password);
        if (login)
            System.out.println("logged In");
        else
            System.out.println("Login Failed!");



    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close_connection() {

    boolean logout = false;
    try {
        logout = f.logout();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (logout) {
        System.out.println("Log out successfull!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("try again!");
    }

    if (f.isConnected())
        try {
            System.out.println("connection is alive!");
            f.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}


//
public  ArrayList getAllFile(String dir) {
    f.enterLocalPassiveMode();
  /*  try {
        f.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
        DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    ArrayList<ArrayList> arrayList= new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    FTPFile[] files = null;
    try {
        files = f.listFiles();
        if(f.isAvailable())
        {
            System.out.println("connected");
        }
        System.out.println("length: "+files.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (FTPFile file : files) {

        ArrayList arrayList1=new ArrayList();

        arrayList1.add(file.getName());

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            arrayList1.add("File Folder");
        }
       else if (file.getName().endsWith(".exe"))
        {
            arrayList1.add("Application");
        }
       else if (file.getName().endsWith(".zip"))
        {
            arrayList1.add("Compressed (Zip Folder)");
        }
       else if (file.getName().endsWith(".xls")||file.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")||file.getName().endsWith(".doc")||file.getName().endsWith(".docx")||file.getName().endsWith(".rtf"))
        {
            arrayList1.add("Microsoft Office Document");
        }
       else if (file.getName().endsWith(".sql"))
        {
            arrayList1.add("SQL File");
        }
       else if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt"))
        {
            arrayList1.add("Text Document");
        }
       else if (file.getName().endsWith(".pdf"))
        {
            arrayList1.add("PDF Document");
        }
        else
        {
            arrayList1.add("File");
        }
        arrayList1.add(dateFormater.format(file.getTimestamp().getTime()));
        arrayList1.add(file.getSize()+" Kb");
        arrayList.add(arrayList1);

                    if(file.isDirectory())
                     System.out.println(file.getName()+": Directory");
                   if(file.isFile())
                      System.out.println(file.getName()+": File");
    }
System.out.println(arrayList);
    return arrayList;

}


//
public void upload(String File_path) throws IOException {

    InputStream input = null;
    String[] File_name = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(File_path);
        File_name = File_path.split("\\\\");
        System.out.println(File_name[File_name.length - 1]);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println(File_name[File_name.length - 1]);
    f.storeFile(File_name[File_name.length - 1], input);
    System.out.println("file uploaded successfully");

    if (input != null)
        input.close();

}



public void download(String from_file_name, String to_path) throws IOException {

    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(to_path + from_file_name);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    f.retrieveFile(from_file_name, output);
    if (output != null) {
        try {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}


}
```

And my output is like
[image]

These are directories of my ftp server now i want to browse subdirectories when a parent directory is clicked, I also want to add a progressbar for file download can anyone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by cunstructor chaining.
Here is second constructor

```
public UndecoratedFrameDemo(final String childdir,Ftp_by_apache ftpByApache2)

{

final Ftp_by_apache ftpByApache12=ftpByApache2;

arrayList1=ftpByApache12.getSublFile(childdir);

System.out.println("initial directory: " + childdir);

final JFrame frame = new JFrame("FTP Client By MPST");

frame.setUndecorated(false);

frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

point.x = e.getX();

point.y = e.getY();

}

});

frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

 Point p = frame.getLocation();

        frame.setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - point.x, p.y + e.getY() - point.y);

         }
         });

    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setLocation(300, 150);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Image icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("ftp-big-icon.jpg").getImage();
    frame.setIconImage(icon);
    Container pane=frame.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(file);

    JMenuItem New = new JMenuItem("New Server");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*code for new ftp server*/
        }
    });
    file.add(New);

    JMenuItem rename = new JMenuItem("Rename");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*code for rename*/
        }
    });
    file.add(rename);

    JMenuItem delete = new JMenuItem("Delete");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*code for delete*/
        }
    });
    file.add(delete);

    JMenuItem connect = new JMenuItem("Connect");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*code for connect to differnt ftp*/
        }
    });
    file.add(connect);

    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    file.add(item);


    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(edit);

    JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /* code for copy*/
        }
    });
    edit.add(copy);

    JMenuItem paste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /* code for Paste*/
        }
    });
    edit.add(paste);
    JMenuItem mkdir = new JMenuItem("New Directory");
    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    file.add(mkdir);

    popup = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem popupcopy= new JMenuItem("Copy");
    popup.add(popupcopy );
    JMenuItem popuprename= new JMenuItem("Rename");
    popup.add( popuprename );
    JMenuItem popupdelete= new JMenuItem("Delete");
    popup.add( popupdelete );
    JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            Component c = (Component)event.getSource();
            JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)c.getParent();
            JTable table = (JTable)popup.getInvoker();

            System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + " : " + table.getSelectedColumn());
            if(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn()+1).equals("File Folder"))
            {

                System.out.println("File Folder Clicked");


                new UndecoratedFrameDemo(childdir+"/"+table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn()).toString(),ftpByApache12);
                // frame.add(table1);
                frame.hide();


            }
            else
            {
                try {


                              ftpByApache12.download(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn()).toString(),"X:/");
            }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    popup.add(menuItem);

    FileTableModel1 fileTableModel1 =new FileTableModel1(arrayList1) ;
    JTable table = new JTable(fileTableModel1)
    {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int column)
        {
            return false;
        }
    };
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                JTable source = (JTable) e.getSource();
                int row = source.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int column = source.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

                if (!source.isRowSelected(row))
                    source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);

                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    });
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // JFilePicker filePicker = new JFilePicker("Save file to: ","Browse...");

    // frame.getContentPane().add(filePicker);







    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```